# Finding indices of non-zero elements in Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like

```
A = [ 0 1 1;0 0 0;1 1 0]
```

For this, I wish to know indices of `1`'s in such a manner that:

For row 1, I need values of indices of column where its coming equal `1`. Similarly for row 2 and row 3.

Later, I want to repeat this exercise for column, like for column 1, I need the value of indices of rows where its coming equal to `1`. and similarly for column 2 and column 3.

The `ans` should be like this :

- *for row 1 - indices are: 2,3*
- *for row 2 - indices are: 0*
- *for row 3 - indices are: 1,2*

Similarly:

- *for column 1 - indices are: 3*
- *for column 2 - indices are: 1,3*
- *for column 3 - indices are: 1*

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[ii jj] = find(A); %// find row and col indices (ii and jj respectively)
rows = accumarray(ii,jj,[], @(v) {sort(v).'}); %'// group jj as per ii, and sort
cols = accumarray(jj,ii,[], @(v) {sort(v).'}); %'// group ii as per jj, and sort
```

For your example, this gives

```
>> rows{:}
ans =
     2     3
ans =
     []
ans =
     1     2
>> cols{:}
ans =
     3
ans =
     1     3
ans =
     1
```

If you really need to fill empty results with a `0`:

```
rows = accumarray(ii,jj,[], @(v) {sort(v).'}, {0}); %'// 5th input is fill value
cols = accumarray(jj,ii,[], @(v) {sort(v).'}, {0});
```

which results in

```
>> rows{:}
ans =
     2     3
ans =
     0
ans =
     1     2
>> cols{:}
ans =
     3
ans =
     1     3
ans =
     1
```

Comment: now just like this we have got two sets of rows and column having 1's in respective arrays, how can we find intersection points for respective arrays of rows and cols. like the ans need to be: >>3 , >> [], >>1. i am trying with intersect command but its turning out with "Too many input arguments". Well once intersection set if found for all respective arrays of rows and col,i just need to rank them on the basis of having minimum elements with highest maximum intersection points. Can you please suggest something for it.

Comment: @NeerajBhanot `arrayfun(@(k) intersect(rows{k}, cols{k}), 1:numel(rows), 'uni', 0)`

Comment: Here is the complete question sir:

Comment: Please check the link below to the complete question that i have posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591831/finding-indexes-intersection-and-then-ranking-in-a-matrix

Comment: I love cell out put with `accumarray`, +1; too bad it requires a `sort` because the first input isn't sorted. I wish it handled this automatically.

Comment: @chappjc Yes; having to use `sort` seems like a waste

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use loops and the `find` function combined with a cell array to store your answer. For example, to get list of the ones in each row:

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
    rowsOne{i} = find(A(i,:)==1);
end
```

`rowsOne{i}` then contains a vector listing the indices of the elements in row i of array A that equal one. If there are no elements that equal 1 in a row, it will hold an empty array.

The solution for the columns is roughly the same.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should stay away from `for` loops in MatLab. They are woefully slow, and there almost always is a built-in function that does what you need in one laconic an quickly executed expression.