# Finding indexes, intersection and then ranking in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix like as follows:

```
a = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 0 0 0 0 0;
     1 0 1 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 0 1 1 0 0;
     1 1 0 1 1 0 0;
     1 0 1 0 0 1 1;
     1 0 1 0 0 1 1]
```

of which i wish to create following table:

```
X - For each Rows index of cols having 1
Y - For each cols index of rows having 1
Z - Intersection set


S.No      X               Y               Z       Rank(Comparing X & Z)
1        1          1,2,3,4,5,6,7        1                 I
2        1,2           2,4,5             2                 II
3        1,3           3,6,7             3                 II
4       1,2,4,5         4,5             4,5                III
5       1,2,4,5         4,5             4,5                III
6       1,3,6,7         6,7             6,7                III
7       1,3,6,7         6,7             6,7                III
```

Of the above table, X and Y columns have been easily found with the help of Matlab code as provided by Sir Luis Mendo to my previous question.
Code was as follows:

```
[ii jj] = find(a); %// find row and col indices (ii and jj respectively)
rows = accumarray(ii,jj,[], @(v) {sort(v).'}); %'// group jj as per ii, and sort
cols = accumarray(jj,ii,[], @(v) {sort(v).'}); %'// group ii as per jj, and sort
rows{:}
cols{:}
```

Now i wish to find intersection set i.e. Z but i m not able to find using intersection command.

Further Ranking is to be done on comparing columns X and Z in such a manner that with minimum of elements in both columns, maximum of common elements should be there and each time that common element should be emitted from the whole X column for further comparison so that again with minimum of elements in both sets max common elements can be found.

Please help.

Comment: Just for readability, don't put **`** in front of code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the intersection, just work with `a & a.'`:

```
[ii jj] = find(a & a.');
z = accumarray(ii,jj,[], @(v) {sort(v).'});
```

Comment: The fact is I don't understand how you want to do the ranking. But it should be easy once you have `x` (previous question) and `z`

Comment: Sir, it is basically based on the fact that first we look in X column having minimum number of elements and then compare it with respective z column. so rank I is given when maximum number of elements match in both of the sets. like here in serial number 1, only one entry was there and it matched with z column. then we have to omit this element ie 1 from other X columns and then again look for minimum elements set to be compared with respective Z set. on this basis ranks are given.

Comment: like in serial number 2 and 3, though elements are not same but there is only element left ie 2 and 3 to be compared with z column and since now we had minimum 2 sets with only element equal to its value in z column, so thats y they were given rank 2. though in between same set of x, their values may be different that is in serial number 2 and 3, number of elements are same though values are different.

Comment: I think it can be done using Union command in such a manner that on applying union on X and Z column, majority of similar elements are given top level and so so forth but i not sure on how to use it.

Comment: For ranking some logic can be applied like for each set of X and Z, union can be applied wherein when on combining two sets no element is added, then its given rank 1 and soon one element is added to a set, then rank increases to 2 and so on. Please let me know if something can be framed out of it. ? Thanks

Comment: @NeerajBhanot Yes, I guess so. You probably need a loop (or `arrayfun`) for that

Comment: Sir, i have been using this command for ranking but its not giving desired result.

r = cellfun(@(x)x(1),cellfun(@(c,v)find(ismember(c,v)),x,z,'un',0),'un',0);

Can u please look into it.?